# Mat-datepicker binding data, but it doesnot display

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an date time picker:

```
   <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [ngModel]="sub?.startDate| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'"  (ngModel)="sub?.startDate" [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker" placeholder="From Date">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #fromDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

the ng model binding data ok, try to f12 I can see it in **ng-reflect-model**:

```
<input _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" matinput="" placeholder="From Date" ng-reflect-mat-datepicker="[object Object]" ng-reflect-placeholder="From Date" aria-haspopup="true" id="mat-input-10" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" ng-reflect-model="01/11/2017">
```

version

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
```

but input filed is empty. please advice me

Comment: Change `(ngModel)` should be `(ngModelChange)="sub?.startDate"`

Comment: @PankajParkar: it's still empty..

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: @PankajParkar: i'm so sorry, i cannot do it right now

Comment: You simply **cannot** use a pipe in your `ngModel` expression. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: @developer033: i try to fill the data(eg.01/11/2017)  to the datetimepicker..

Comment: @PankajParkar: i try to remove  [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker"  on input, the value of model can display successfully. it 's strange

Comment: Try to follow these steps: [setting-the-locale-code](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code).